# Unexpected pageInfo from YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I've tried to search videos using YouTube Data API  v3 (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).
I successfully got some information, but I figured out the result of `pageInfo` wasn't something I expected.

Here is the query and the response I got:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId=UC5fslQUCCo3OE1EaA1n5ZmQ&key=...&publishedAfter=2019-01-15T08:09:38Z&publishedBefore=2019-01-15T10:09:38Z&order=date` .

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "iLvO2LgGDksqADNU-_xPwG4QMCU",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "JP",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 49,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "Adtll-9lbQDiKGJEkBb2IEjPfjw",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "d4Z7MZo3-Ac"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I specified date strings to `publishAfter` and `publishBefore` so that the result include single video information only.
I guessed both `pageInfo.totalResult` and `pageInfo.resultPerPage` were 1.
Contrary to my anticipation, `pageInfo.totalResult` was 49 and `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` was 5.

What describes `pageInfo`? Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the answers to your two questions:

**1. Why `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` is `5`?**

The specification of this property is the following:

> [**`pageInfo.resultsPerPage`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.resultsPerPage) (integer)
> The number of results included in the API response.

One may read this specification as (am rephrasing the text above): the number of items in the result set obtained from the API, i.e the number of elements of the JSON array `items`.

Unfortunately, this does not correspond to reality. In my experience, `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` is simply the value of the request parameter `maxResults`:

> [**`maxResults`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#maxResults) (unsigned integer)
> The `maxResults` parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are `0` to `50`, inclusive. The default value is `5`.

Since your API invoking URL above does not specify `maxResults`, this parameter is taken as having the default value; hence `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` gets to be 5.

One more remark: indeed the official specification of this property is misleading; this issue may well be reported to Google (via its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/)) as a documentation bug.

**2. Why `pageInfo.totalResults` is `49` and is not `1`?**

The specification of this property is the following (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**`pageInfo.totalResults`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) (integer)
> The total number of results in the result set. *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value.* In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

According to this specification, `pageInfo.totalResults` is not to be taken as a precise quantity that the user can rely upon. This peculiarity [is also confirmed officially](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155088389#comment2) by Google's staff.

Moreover, if experimenting a bit with your URL, eliminating the two date request parameters `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore`, you'll see that the value of `pageInfo.totalResults` becomes unstable: repeating the same API call several times in a row (only seconds apart one from another), I never got the same value of out of the API, but, alternating, `1374` and `1375`.

Comment: I got it.  
The answer for the first question is the almost same as what I've guessed in advance.  
  
I’m surprised about the second.  
In short, pageInfo.totalResult is totally useless, right?   
Surprisingly,  Japanese version of this documentation doesn’t mention that part. That’s why I didn’t be able to notice this defect.  
  
I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Akumachan: until its semantics is not changed, `pageInfo.totalResults` is indeed useless; I myself never take this property into account when using the API.

Comment: @Akumachan: Then please report to Google via its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/) that the Japanese doc w.r.t. `Search.list` API endpoint's `pageInfo.totalResults` property is bogus. They should fix it such that your fellow countrymen to no fall short as happened to you.

Comment: Thanks, I reported this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174686919)

Comment: @Akumachan: Thanks for reporting! I would however ask you to mention within that report the culprit API endpoint doc -- the `Search.list` endpoint's doc --, also providing a link to that page too. You may also indicate to Google staff (which probably don't understand Japanese) that the Japanese translation is missing something that on the English page reads as: *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value*. That's the precise bug of that Japanese doc.

Comment: @Akumachan: I myself had a look at that Japanese translation. It reads simply as *結果セット内の結果の総数。* Compared to the English version -- which presumably is the source of the translation --, the Japanese version in missing quite of lot of text specifying `pageInfo.totalResults`: Google's translation web page produces for the mentioned Japanese text the following *The total number of results in the result set.* Therefore, I deem that the Japanese version is missing very important specifications of `pageInfo.totalResults`.

Comment: @Akumachan: I'll mention here an interesting thing I discovered while reading the specs of [`pageInfo.totalResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) in all the languages for which the API has translations of those specs. *None of the versions of that spec in a language different that English has a translation that [Google's translation web service](http://translate.google.com) will show to parallel closely the original (the source) English version.*

Comment: @Akumachan: The lesson learned from here is: *it may well be in the very interest of non-native English speaking API users  to consider not using translated YouTube Data API docs*, since those translations would likely be missing relevant details of which absence impede the effective usage of those APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed research. I reported detail of problem. I'm going to use original version of documents in order to obtain accurate information from now on. Thank you so much again.